# Preciso transforma uma lista no Power Query em uma nova coluna de uma tabela específica

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Eu importei meus dados a partir de uma tabela .xlsx e preciso criar uma nova tabela a partir do somatório de valores contidos em outras colunas da minha tabela importada. Na tabela importada, essas colunas são apresentadas com o 'header' em datas, por exemplo, "01/01/2022" "01/02/2022", assim sucessivamente. Na minha nova tabela preciso criar 3 novas colunas, uma para data, como tudo é relacionado a "2022" pode ser apenas os meses apresentados {"janeiro", "fevereiro"....}. No PowerQuery adicionei uma nova tabela e a primeira coluna implementei manualmente os meses, e fui em "adicionar nova coluna", e a seguinte formula foi executada `= Table.AddColumn(#"Tipo Alterado1", "Orçado", each {List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "1/1/2022")), List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "2/1/2022")), List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "3/1/2022")), List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "4/1/2022")), List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "5/1/2022")), List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "6/1/2022")), List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "7/1/2022")), List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "8/1/2022")), List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "9/1/2022")), List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "10/1/2022")), List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "11/1/2022")), List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "12/1/2022"))})`.

No coluna sendo "Orçado" a partir de uma lista, criada de acordo com a somatória de valores de cada coluna dos meus dados importados. A questão é que, de fato consegui com a lista o que eu queria, porém minha coluna não foi a desejada, pois cada célula está a lista completa de valores, aos invés de distribuir cada item da lista para cada célula. Como podemos ver abaixo:
[Tabela power bi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edbKw.png)

Então decidi criar a lista através de uma consulta, dessa forma `= {List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "1/1/2022")), List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "2/1/2022")), List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "3/1/2022")), List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "4/1/2022")), List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "5/1/2022")), List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "6/1/2022")), List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "7/1/2022")), List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "8/1/2022")), List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "9/1/2022")), List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "10/1/2022")), List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "11/1/2022")), List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Dados (2)", "12/1/2022"))}` deu certo, conforme figura: [lista](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhHCM.png). Porém não consigo da mesma forma importar valores para minha tabela, pois diz que são valores em formato 'text'. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Pesquisando mais a fundo consegui resolver. Levando em consideração o que eu queria fazer, porém com uma coluna a mais agora, além de de "Data" e "Orçado", também terá um coluna com "Realizado" e meus dados originais que antes relatei como "Dados (2), agora é "Dados origem". Para isso basta fazer:

```
    Table.Combine({
Table.FromColumns({
List.Repeat({"01/01/2022"}, Table.RowCount(#"Dados origem")),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "1/1/2022"),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "Realizado 01/22 "),
},
{"Data", "Orçado", "Realizado"}
),
Table.FromColumns({
List.Repeat({"02/01/2022"}, Table.RowCount(#"Dados origem")),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "2/1/2022"),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "Realizado 02/22 "),
},
{"Data", "Orçado", "Realizado"}
),
Table.FromColumns({
List.Repeat({"03/01/2022"}, Table.RowCount(#"Dados origem")),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "3/1/2022"),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "Realizado 03/22"),
},
{"Data", "Orçado", "Realizado"}
),
Table.FromColumns({
List.Repeat({"04/01/2022"}, Table.RowCount(#"Dados origem")),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "4/1/2022"),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "Realizado 04/22"),
},
{"Data", "Orçado", "Realizado"}
),
Table.FromColumns({
List.Repeat({"05/01/2022"}, Table.RowCount(#"Dados origem")),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "5/1/2022"),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "Realizado 05/22"),
},
{"Data", "Orçado", "Realizado"}
),
Table.FromColumns({
List.Repeat({"06/01/2022"}, Table.RowCount(#"Dados origem")),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "6/1/2022"),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "Realizado 06/22"),
},
{"Data", "Orçado", "Realizado"}
),
Table.FromColumns({
List.Repeat({"07/01/2022"}, Table.RowCount(#"Dados origem")),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "7/1/2022"),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "Realizado 07/22"),
},
{"Data", "Orçado", "Realizado"}
),
Table.FromColumns({
List.Repeat({"08/01/2022"}, Table.RowCount(#"Dados origem")),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "8/1/2022"),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "Realizado 08/22"),
},
{"Data", "Orçado", "Realizado"}
),
Table.FromColumns({
List.Repeat({"09/01/2022"}, Table.RowCount(#"Dados origem")),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "9/1/2022"),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "Realizado 09/22"),
},
{"Data", "Orçado", "Realizado"}
),
Table.FromColumns({
List.Repeat({"10/01/2022"}, Table.RowCount(#"Dados origem")),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "10/1/2022"),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "Realizado 10/22"),
},
{"Data", "Orçado", "Realizado"}
),
Table.FromColumns({
List.Repeat({"11/01/2022"}, Table.RowCount(#"Dados origem")),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "11/1/2022"),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "Realizado 11/22"),
},
{"Data", "Orçado", "Realizado"}
),
Table.FromColumns({
List.Repeat({"12/01/2022"}, Table.RowCount(#"Dados origem")),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "12/1/2022"),
Table.Column(#"Dados origem", "Realizado 12/22"),
},
{"Data", "Orçado", "Realizado"}
)
})
```

A saída será algo desse tipo: [saída Power Bi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oKEO.png)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).